# When to use GeometryField?

Tags: geodjango

I'm trying to understand what is the point of GeometryField.  The GeoDjango docs don't say much and neither do questions on Stack.  What is special about it?  When would you use it over PolygonField/PointField/etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GeometryField can hold either a `Point`, a `LineString` or a `Polygon`.

An example:  Your table holds information about parks in your city.  Your data is incomplete - and for some parks the data is a single point in the park, but for other parks the information is complete and the whole park is detailed as a polygon.

Note: Although this is possible, I would recommend against using this method as it will probably make your code much more complicated - requiring to handle and detect different geom types in a single field.  In the example above I would have used two columns - one with a required point field and one with an optional polygon.

Comment: Another case when you might want a GeometryField instead of (e.g) a MultiPolygonField is if you want to use PostGIS to perform operations like *Intersection* or *MakeValid* on your polygons. These methods (validly) can return points and lines as well as polygons which you would be unable to then save in your MultiPolygonField.